# Mails are not senting from Panelboxmanager to some domains

Tags: email-server, gmail

I've some email ids on our hosting server  on [funio.com](https://funio.com). I'm experiencing mail delivery failure in my email address , mail@mydomain.com.

The screenshot of the error[image]

Error details

[image]

While contacting funio supporting center, they replied the following details

> Only mail@mydomain.com is unable to send mails to
>   support@funio.com 
>            which is hosted with Google and part of a group.
>
> ```
>      To solve this problem for mail@mydomain.com here is what you need to do:
>      https://support.google.com/a/answer/3237621?hl=en
> ```

I really don't understand and I'm very new to Google group as they said in the answer. I didn't do anything with the Google groups with my email id.I tried to login using mail@mydomain.com in gmail. How can I rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your account is part of a google group, or a google apps (or google g suite) domain, It's telling you that the account that is sending to that address is currently disabled, probably locked by the admin for some reason.

If you are the user, you should login at https://accounts.google.com and check the status. You could also contact your domain administrator if you are not the one responsible for the email accounts at the google g suite.